Docker compose issue with mongo db and spring boot
I am trying to connect my spring boot app to docker mongo db using compose but it unable to connect I have an uri in application.properties that i need to override or will connect to atlas mongodb what is the issue with hostname I am giving the right host name but can't find to see the problem
   mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: mongodb-container
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=root1234
 
  wishlist-service:
    image: tejajagadeep/movie-app-wishlist-service:latest
    container_name: wishlist-container
    environment:
      - eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://eureka-server:8761/eureka
      - spring.config.import=optional:configserver:http://config-server:8888/
      - management.zipkin.tracing.endpoint=http://zipkin-server:9411/api/v2/spans
      - swagger.server.url=http://localhost:8769/,http://localhost:4200/
      - spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://root:root1234@mongodb:27017/wishlistdb
    ports:
      - "8082:8082"
    networks:
      - my-movie-network
    depends_on:
      - eureka-server
      - config-server
      - mongodb
    links:
      - eureka-server
      - config-server
      - mongodb
      - zipkin-server
    restart: on-failure
    entrypoint: sh -c "apk --no-cache add curl && /bin/sh -c 'until curl -sSf http://config-server:8888/actuator/health; do echo \"Waiting for config-server to be healthy...\"; sleep 5; done' && java -jar /usr/src/wishlist-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:8082/actuator/health"]
      interval: 20s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 10


2024-05-07 14:07:57 2024-05-07T08:37:57.109Z  WARN 1 --- [wishlist-service] [nio-8082-exec-4] [6639e84778fe14eccb111730936a9e2b-cb111730936a9e2b] o.s.b.a.data.mongo.MongoHealthIndicator  : MongoDB health check failed
2024-05-07 14:07:57 
2024-05-07 14:07:57 org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary}. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=mongodb:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: mongodb}, caused by {java.net.UnknownHostException: mongodb}}]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MongoExceptionTranslator.java:88) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.2.4.jar!/:4.2.4]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.potentiallyConvertRuntimeException(MongoTemplate.java:2997) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.2.4.jar!/:4.2.4]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:582) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.2.4.jar!/:4.2.4]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeCommand(MongoTemplate.java:514) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.2.4.jar!/:4.2.4]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.springframework.boot.actuate.data.mongo.MongoHealthIndicator.doHealthCheck(MongoHealthIndicator.java:46) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.2.4.jar!/:3.2.4]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.AbstractHealthIndicator.health(AbstractHealthIndicator.java:82) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.2.4.jar!/:3.2.4]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicator.getHealth(HealthIndicator.java:37) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.2.4.jar!/:3.2.4]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointWebExtension.getHealth(HealthEndpointWebExtension.java:94) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.2.4.jar!/:3.2.4]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointWebExtension.getHealth(HealthEndpointWebExtension.java:47) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.2.4.jar!/:3.2.4]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getLoggedHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:172) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.2.4.jar!/:3.2.4]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:145) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.2.4.jar!/:3.2.4]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getAggregateContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:156) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.2.4.jar!/:3.2.4]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:141) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.2.4.jar!/:3.2.4]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:110) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.2.4.jar!/:3.2.4]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:81) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.2.4.jar!/:3.2.4]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointWebExtension.health(HealthEndpointWebExtension.java:80) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.2.4.jar!/:3.2.4]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointWebExtension.health(HealthEndpointWebExtension.java:69) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.2.4.jar!/:3.2.4]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:281) ~[spring-core-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.invoke.reflect.ReflectiveOperationInvoker.invoke(ReflectiveOperationInvoker.java:74) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.2.4.jar!/:3.2.4]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.AbstractDiscoveredOperation.invoke(AbstractDiscoveredOperation.java:60) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.2.4.jar!/:3.2.4]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$ServletWebOperationAdapter.handle(AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping.java:327) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.2.4.jar!/:3.2.4]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping.java:434) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.2.4.jar!/:3.2.4]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:255) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:188) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:830) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.springframework.web.filter.ServerHttpObservationFilter.doFilterInternal(ServerHttpObservationFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831) ~[na:na]
2024-05-07 14:07:57 Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary}. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=mongodb:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: mongodb}, caused by {java.net.UnknownHostException: mongodb}}]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at com.mongodb.internal.connection.BaseCluster.createTimeoutException(BaseCluster.java:380) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.11.1.jar!/:na]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at com.mongodb.internal.connection.BaseCluster.selectServer(BaseCluster.java:125) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.11.1.jar!/:na]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SingleServerCluster.selectServer(SingleServerCluster.java:46) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.11.1.jar!/:na]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at com.mongodb.internal.binding.ClusterBinding.getReadConnectionSource(ClusterBinding.java:116) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.11.1.jar!/:na]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at com.mongodb.client.internal.ClientSessionBinding.getConnectionSource(ClientSessionBinding.java:128) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-4.11.1.jar!/:na]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at com.mongodb.client.internal.ClientSessionBinding.getReadConnectionSource(ClientSessionBinding.java:92) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-4.11.1.jar!/:na]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at com.mongodb.internal.operation.SyncOperationHelper.withSuppliedResource(SyncOperationHelper.java:144) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.11.1.jar!/:na]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at com.mongodb.internal.operation.SyncOperationHelper.withSourceAndConnection(SyncOperationHelper.java:125) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.11.1.jar!/:na]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at com.mongodb.internal.operation.SyncOperationHelper.lambda$executeRetryableRead$4(SyncOperationHelper.java:189) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.11.1.jar!/:na]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at com.mongodb.internal.operation.SyncOperationHelper.lambda$decorateReadWithRetries$12(SyncOperationHelper.java:292) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.11.1.jar!/:na]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at com.mongodb.internal.async.function.RetryingSyncSupplier.get(RetryingSyncSupplier.java:67) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.11.1.jar!/:na]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at com.mongodb.internal.operation.SyncOperationHelper.executeRetryableRead(SyncOperationHelper.java:194) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.11.1.jar!/:na]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at com.mongodb.internal.operation.SyncOperationHelper.executeRetryableRead(SyncOperationHelper.java:176) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.11.1.jar!/:na]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at com.mongodb.internal.operation.CommandReadOperation.execute(CommandReadOperation.java:48) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.11.1.jar!/:na]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.execute(MongoClientDelegate.java:153) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-4.11.1.jar!/:na]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoDatabaseImpl.executeCommand(MongoDatabaseImpl.java:196) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-4.11.1.jar!/:na]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoDatabaseImpl.runCommand(MongoDatabaseImpl.java:165) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-4.11.1.jar!/:na]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoDatabaseImpl.runCommand(MongoDatabaseImpl.java:160) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-4.11.1.jar!/:na]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.lambda$executeCommand$3(MongoTemplate.java:514) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.2.4.jar!/:4.2.4]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:580) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.2.4.jar!/:4.2.4]
2024-05-07 14:07:57     ... 77 common frames omitted
2024-05-07 14:07:57 
2024-05-07 14:07:57 2024-05-07T08:37:57.112Z  WARN 1 --- [wishlist-service] [nio-8082-exec-4] [6639e84778fe14eccb111730936a9e2b-cb111730936a9e2b] o.s.b.a.health.HealthEndpointSupport     : Health contributor org.springframework.boot.actuate.data.mongo.MongoHealthIndicator (mongo) took 30003ms to respond
2024-05-07 14:07:57 2024-05-07T08:37:57.138Z  INFO 1 --- [wishlist-service] [nio-8082-exec-5] [                                                 ] c.c.w.aspects.LoggingAspect              : Method returned: false
2024-05-07 14:07:57 2024-05-07T08:37:57.140Z  INFO 1 --- [wishlist-service] [nio-8082-exec-5] [6639e86556a0b85d83c2a8284cdea40e-83c2a8284cdea40e] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : No server chosen by ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary} from cluster description ClusterDescription{type=UNKNOWN, connectionMode=SINGLE, serverDescriptions=[ServerDescription{address=mongodb:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: mongodb}, caused by {java.net.UnknownHostException: mongodb}}]}. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out

What should I give here I tries many things still not connecting

Your mongodb container is not on the same network as the spring boot container and can therefore not reach it. You need to specify the same network for the mongodb container.
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: mongodb-container
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=root1234
    networks: # Make sure to put all containers on the same network
      - my-movie-network # Name of the network


yeah forgot that thank you but still facing the different issue resource not found

- spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://root:root1234@mongodb:27017/wishlistdb?authSource=admin 

source admin we need to add

If you delete all of the networks: blocks in the entire file, Compose will connect all of the containers to a network named default, which will also have the same effect.
